# Unsupported argument output

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have the next config.

main.tf

./modules/vpc

vpc.tf

./modules/compute_engine

ce.tf

on main I have

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "./modules/vpc"
}

module "compute_engine_controller" {
  source = "./modules/compute_engine"
  vpc_name = module.vpc.vpc_network_name
}
```

on vpc I have

```
output "vpc_network_name" {
  value = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name
}
```

on ce I have

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "controller" {
...
  network_interface {
    network = var.vpc_name
  }
...
}
```

I get an error

> │ Error: Unsupported argument
> │
> │   on main.tf line 34, in module "compute_engine_controller":
> │   34:     vpc_name = module.vpc.vpc_network_name
> │
> │ An argument named "vpc_name" is not expected here.

why?

Comment: What is the definition of `"./modules/compute_engine"` module?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you referring to but I'm creating a google compute instance  on the ce.tf, edited post.

Comment: @BernardoRebelo This is not a properly defined terraform code: `network = vpc_network_name`. It could only be `network = var.vpc_network_name`.

Comment: my problem is that he can't even do  vpc_name = module.vpc.vpc_network_name on main

Comment: Nope, your module is complaining that it does not expect a variable with name `vpc_name`. Maybe it is in fact `vpc_network_name`, i.e., `vpc_netowrk_name = module.vpc.vpc_network_name`?

Comment: it still gives the same error the vpc_name was a typo on my end

Comment: Ok, and have you defined a variable called `vpc_name` in your CE module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253363/discussion-between-bernardo-rebelo-and-marko-e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the module is complaining about not expecting an argument called `vpc_name`, that means that the corresponding variable has not been defined in the `variables.tf` of the module. To fix this, what needs to be added is:

```
variable "vpc_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the VPC to be used."
}
```